# Memory leak in a join string function

Tags: c, memory-leaks, string-concatenation, c-strings, function-definition

I'm trying to make a function that join 2 strings (str1 & str2) into a new one (str3) seperated by a char seperator. Unfortunately I have a memory leak from this function and I don't really know why since I free str3 at the end.

Example: str_join_string("ABC","DEF",'|') ---> "ABC|DEF"

Here's the code:

```c
char *str_join_string(const char *str1, const char *str2, char separator) {
  char *str3;
  size_t len = str_length(str1)+ str_length(str2)+1;
  size_t i = 0;
  size_t j = 0;

  str3 = (char * )calloc(len, sizeof(char));
  if(str3 == NULL){
    printf("Impossible d'allouer la mémoire");
    return NULL;
  }
  

  while(str1[i] != '\0' && str1 != NULL){
    str3[i] = str1[i];
    i++;
  }
  str3[i] = separator;
  i+=1;

  while(str2[j] != '\0' && str2 != NULL){
    str3[i+j] = str2[j];
    j++;
  }
  str3[len] = '\0';
  
  return str3;
}
```

I will add that I can't use any function like strcat() or anything that comes from string.h.

What Valgrind shows:

```
==4300== Searching for pointers to 3 not-freed blocks
==4300== Checked 131,560 bytes
==4300== 
==4300== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 3
==4300==    at 0x4C31B25: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4300==    by 0x13E3B2: str_join_string (stringslib.c:238)
==4300==    by 0x13E545: str_join_array (stringslib.c:283)
==4300==    by 0x137065: JoinArrayTest_OneEmpty_Test::TestBody() (stringslib_test.cc:779)
==4300==    by 0x1652A9: HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void> (gtest.cc:2611)
==4300==    by 0x1652A9: void testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest.cc:2647)
==4300==    by 0x15A9DE: testing::Test::Run() [clone .part.658] (gtest.cc:2686)
==4300==    by 0x15AC61: Run (gtest.cc:2677)
==4300==    by 0x15AC61: testing::TestInfo::Run() [clone .part.659] (gtest.cc:2863)
==4300==    by 0x15B350: Run (gtest.cc:2837)
==4300==    by 0x15B350: testing::TestSuite::Run() [clone .part.660] (gtest.cc:3017)
==4300==    by 0x15BAF4: Run (gtest.cc:2997)
==4300==    by 0x15BAF4: testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests() (gtest.cc:5709)
==4300==    by 0x165769: HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool> (gtest.cc:2611)
==4300==    by 0x165769: bool testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest.cc:2647)
==4300==    by 0x15AD82: testing::UnitTest::Run() (gtest.cc:5292)
==4300==    by 0x11C08E: RUN_ALL_TESTS (gtest.h:2485)
==4300==    by 0x11C08E: main (stringslib_test.cc:799)
==4300==
```

I hope that you can help me because I'm really lost right now.

------EDIT------
Yes I completely forgot to add the caller which is where I free the memory:

```c
TEST(JoinStringTest, Simple) {
  char *buf = str_join_string("ABC", "XYZ", '|');
  ASSERT_TRUE(buf != NULL);
  EXPECT_EQ(buf[0], 'A');
  EXPECT_EQ(buf[1], 'B');
  EXPECT_EQ(buf[2], 'C');
  EXPECT_EQ(buf[3], '|');
  EXPECT_EQ(buf[4], 'X');
  EXPECT_EQ(buf[5], 'Y');
  EXPECT_EQ(buf[6], 'Z');
  EXPECT_EQ(buf[7], '\0');
  free(buf);
}
```

Comment: When a function returns, it has finished executing.  Your `free(str3)` line will never be called and is "dead code".  `str_join_string` *cannot* free `str3` anyway since it's returning it to the caller; the *caller* must be responsible for freeing the returned value when it no longer needs it.

Comment: Indeed, I just forgot to add the caller to the post which is where I use free() I will delete thos lines of code. Sorry.

Comment: What is `str_length()`?  How does it differ from the standard library's `strlen()`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger str_length() return the same result as strlen() but for this assignment it was forbidden to use strlen() I had to make one myself.

Comment: Are you sure you've presented the test to which Valgrind attributes the leak?  `JoinArrayTest_OneEmpty_Test::TestBody()` from Valgrind's stack trace does not appear to match up with `TEST(JoinStringTest, Simple)`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, In fact I have others memory leaks from one other function but when I put str_join_string() in a comment those memory leaks disapeared. I think str_join_string() is the main cause of those memory leaks because I use it in the other function too. If you think I should add it I can add it.

Comment: @ArthurBtrd, I think the `str_join_str()` function presented has the problems that Vlad pointed out, and no others.  Those are genuine problems, and they should be corrected, but they probably do not explain the memory leaks Valgrind is reporting.  Those would arise from that function's *caller* failing to free the memory it allocates (or passing on that responsibility to another function that faithfully discharges it).

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Okay, that would explain why even though I changed everything I still have those 4 bytes of memory leak. My teacher is the one who gave us the Test file which contain the function's caller so I don't see why that souldn't work. Anyway thank you and sorry that I have taken your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the function invokes undefined behavior because there is not enough memory allocated for the result string.

Instead of

```
size_t len = str_length(str1)+ str_length(str2)+1;
```

you have to write

```
size_t len = str_length(str1)+ str_length(str2)+2;
```

Moreover this statement

```
str3[len] = '\0';
```

also tries to write to the memory outside the allocated array.

It seems you mean

```
str3[i + j] = '\0';
```

Though you could remove this statement because you are using the function `calloc` that sets the allocated memory with zeroes. On the other hand, using `calloc` is inefficient in the function context.

And statements after the return statement

```
//...
return str3;
free(str3);
str3 = NULL;
```

are never executed.

Pay attention to that conditions like in this for loop

```
while(str1[i] != '\0' && str1 != NULL){
```

do not make a sense. At least the operands of the logical AND operator shall be exchanged like

```
while( str1 != NULL && str1[i] != '\0' ){
```

Though in any case the condition `str1 != NULL` is redundant or you could check the condition before the loop in an if statement.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be defined (without using standard string functions)  and called.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t str_length( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;
    
    while ( *s++ ) ++n;
    
    return n;
}

char * str_join_string( const char *s1, const char *s2, char separator ) 
{
    size_t n = str_length( s1 ) + str_length( s2 ) + sizeof( separator ) + 1;
    
    char *s3 = malloc( n );
    
    if ( s3 )
    {
        char *p = s3;
        
        for ( ; *s1; ++s1 ) *p++ = *s1;
        
        *p++ = separator;
        
        for ( ; *s2; ++s2 ) *p++ = *s2;
        
        *p = '\0';
    }
    
    
    return s3;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = str_join_string( "ABC", "DEF", '|' );
    
    if ( s ) puts( s );
    
    free( s );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ABC|DEF
```

It is the user of the function shall provide arguments not equal to `NULL`.

Comment: You seem to know what the non-standard `str_length()` function does.  Or are you assuming that the OP has misspelled `strlen`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I suppose that he needs to write the function without using standard string functions. Otherwise instead of loops he used standard string functions.

Comment: That could well be, but if so, how can you be sure that it's not counting string terminators in its return value, whether erroneously or by design, so as to conclude that not enough memory is allocated?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Because otherwise he allocated more memory than required.

Comment: Which would be a different issue, and not erroneous.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree.:)

Comment: @JohnBollinger, it is just like Vlad from Moscow, said I had to make a function without the standard string function. I don't think that in the str_len() function I count the string terminator, do I need to show you ?

Comment: No, @ArthurBtrd.  I was merely pointing out to Vlad that one part of this answer hinges on an (at the time) unsupported assumption on his part.  Not counting the terminator is the right thing to do if you are trying to emulate `strlen()`,but it does mean that, as Vlad says, you are not allocating enough memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
return str3;
free(str3);
```

Looks at this snippet, do you think `free()` is ever going to get called?

Comment: But that's good, because if it did the returned pointer would be dangling.

Comment: You're right, I just forgot to delete this of the code, I added the caller which is where I free().

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you return your function first and THEN free your buffer!?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/return-statement-c?view=vs-2019

> A return statement ends the execution of a function, and returns
> control to the calling function

Comment: It would be worse if he did it in the other order, since he would be returning an invalid pointer.